# google.script.run not returning string

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-apps-script, google-docs

Trying to figure out Google Apps Script for making Google docs addons.
I have:

#### Code.gs

```
function helloWorld() {
    return "Hello World";
}
```

under code.gs which I call in:

#### Sidebar.html

```
console.log("This should say Hello World: " + google.script.run.helloWorld())
```

It returns:

```
This should say Hello World: undefined
```

What is the obvious thing I am missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`google.script.run` won't return a value like you'd expect a usual Apps Script function to. Instead, you should use [`.withSuccessHandler(functionToRun)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#withsuccesshandlerfunction)

Like this:

```
    google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler(functionToRun)
        .helloWorld();

    function functionToRun(argument) {
        console.log("This should say Hello World: " + argument);
    }
```

In this example, the server-side Apps Script function `helloWorld` will run the client-side function `functionToRun()` and pass the result of `helloWorld()` as an argument.

Comment: I think I understand. It might take a little bit to click but my code is working now thank you!