# Google Sheets Script Editor HTML User Interface not able to read return type

Tags: javascript, html, user-interface, google-apps-script, return

I am attempting to take a custom array from the script editor and return it to my HTML UI in order to create a customized drop down menu search bar.

The first major problem I am encountering is that I am unable to assign a variable to a value from a function's return type. Below is the code I have written:

CODE:

```
function showSidebar() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Search5')
      .setTitle('My custom sidebar')
      .setWidth(300);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
      .showSidebar(html);
}

function called(value){
   Logger.log("CALLED");
   Logger.log(value);
   var html= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Search5').setTitle("NEW sidebar");
   SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);
}

function getArray(){
   Logger.log("get array called");
   var array = ["test","a", "b", "c"];
   return array;

}

function counter(i){
    Logger.log(i);
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

   <head>
      <title>HTML form Tag</title>
   </head>

   <body>
   <form action="" method = "get">
    <select name="cars" id = "test">
      <div id="wrapper"></div>
      <option value="volvo">Volvo XC90</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab 95</option>
      <option value="mercedes">Mercedes SLK</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi TT</option>
      <option value="select">SELECTED</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi TT</option>

    </select>
     <input type="submit" name = "submitButton" onclick = "get()" value="Submit">
   </form>
    <script>

   var array[];

   function get(){
      var e = document.getElementById("test");
      var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
      google.script.run.called(strUser);
    }
   function read(){
      array = google.script.run.getArray();
      google.script.run.counter(9);  //debugging purposes
    }
    function test(){
        google.script.run.counter();
    }
    function addHtml(){
    read();  
    google.script.run.counter(array[3]); //debugging purpoes
    var text = "";
    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { 
       text += '<option value="' + i+ '">'+ i+ '</option>\n';
        google.script.run.counter(text); //debugging purposes
      } 
      document.getElementById("wrapper").innerHTML = text;
    }
    window.onload = function () {
     addHtml();
    }
    </script>
   </body>

</html>
```

The line of code

```
      document.getElementById("wrapper").innerHTML = text;
```

is intended to customize the drop down menu options. However, that doesn't seem to be working as well despite extensive research.

Back to the original question, why is my HTML code unable to assign the return type from my script to the javascript variable within my HTML file?

Thanks.

Comment: I apologize for my poor English skill. What meaning is "the return type from my script to the javascript variable"?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. My javascript variable inside the HTML code array should be assigned to the return type of the method getArray() from this line of code:       array = google.script.run.getArray();
. Although getArray() correctly returns an array, my array variable in the HTML code does not get assigned to the array in my script.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I posted a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [google.script.run not returning string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41527845/google-script-run-not-returning-string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You want to use the values from `getArray()` of Google Apps Script at Javascript.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### Modification points:

- Modify from `var array[];` to `var array = [];`.
- Move `<div id="wrapper"></div>` to outside of `select`.

  - In your current script, I think that an error occurs.
- `google.script.run` doesn't return values. When you want to use the returned values from Google Apps Script side, please use `withSuccessHandler()`.
- `google.script.run` works with the asynchronous process.

  - In your script, when `addHtml()` is run, `google.script.run.counter(array[3])` and the for loop is run before `read()` is finished. By this, the undefined array is used.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

In this modification, your Javascript was modified.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>HTML form Tag</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form action="" method = "get">
      <div id="wrapper"></div> <!-- Modified -->
      <select name="cars" id = "test">
        <option value="volvo">Volvo XC90</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab 95</option>
        <option value="mercedes">Mercedes SLK</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi TT</option>
        <option value="select">SELECTED</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi TT</option>
      </select>
      <input type="submit" name = "submitButton" onclick = "get()" value="Submit">
    </form>

    <script>
      var array = []; // Modified

      function get(){
        var e = document.getElementById("test");
        var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
        google.script.run.called(strUser);
      }

      function test(){
        google.script.run.counter();
      }

      function read() { // Modified
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(addHtml).getArray();
      }

      function addHtml(e){ // Modified
        array = e;
        var text = "";
        for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { 
          text += '<option value="' + i+ '">'+ i+ '</option>\n';
        }
        document.getElementById("wrapper").innerHTML = text;
      }

      window.onload = function() {
        read(); // Modified
      }
    </script>

  </body>

</html>
```

#### References:

- [Class google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)
- [withSuccessHandler(function)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#withSuccessHandler(Function))

Comment: Thank you Tanaike! You have resolved my issue with the return type. However, my drop down search bar does not include those additional array options I have read. What do you think is the problem here?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured that adding the entire form as a code block, rather than the options itself, was enough to solve my issue. Cheers!

Comment: @Mahmoud Maarouf Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.